# Every map $f:S^2\to S^2$ has a fixpoint or maps a point to its antipodal

Tags: algebraic-topology

By the hairy ball theorem it is enough to give a vector field $V:S^2\to \mathbb R^3$ such that $V(P)\cdot P=0$ and $$V(P)=0 \iff f(P)=P \vee f(P)=P^*$$
However, I'm having trouble constructing such a $V$, is there some trick that I am missing, or some way to show it exists without constructing it?

Comment: Assuming to the contrary, there is a unique shortest path from each $P$ to $f(P)$ (an arc). Let $V(p)$ be the differential of this path at $t=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If $f$, $g\colon S^2\to S^2$ are such that $f(p)$, $g(p)$ are not opposite, for all $p\in S^2$, then $f$, $g$ are homotopic
2. If $f(p) \ne -p$ for all $p$ then $f$ and $Id$ are homotopic
3. If $f(p) \ne  -(-p)$ for all $p$ then $f$ and $-Id$ are homotopic.

Now, if $f$ is like in the statement, then $f\simeq Id, -Id$, so $Id$ and $-Id$ are homotopic. That should give a contradiction.